# Get index of child using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, parent-child

I want to get the index of the clicked child

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="c1"></div>
        <div class="c2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="c1"></div>
        <div class="c2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="c1"></div>
        <div class="c2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.child .c1').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().index())
})
```

I always get -1. How can i do this work?

---

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
$('.child .c1').click(function(){
    alert($(this).index())
})
```

The result is -1 all the time.
What could be wrong?

Comment: Your code works just fine the way it is.

Comment: No real problem here http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/wpKkm/

Comment: Works for me, too. Can you make a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Taken from the jQuery API `If the element is not found, .index() will return -1.`

Comment: Only way the element wouldn't be found would be if `this` didn't have a `.parent()`. And if it was clicked, that means it's in the DOM, and it does have a parent.

Comment: ...flagging as "unclear". There's no issue shown, and OP doesn't want to respond.

Comment: @user2615024 - You should try using the latest version of jQuery if you are not already. Also, do some debugging with your code alert($(this).length); alert($(this).parent().length); give us the results of those two statements

Comment: @user: Whatever the problem is, you've left it out of the question. Seems like you're providing a overly simplified version of your actual code. Please post your actual JS and HTML. Please also provide all other relevant information like browser and version, and jQuery version.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var child_index = '';

$('.c1').click(function() {

  var parent = $(this).parent();


  child_index = $(parent).index();

  alert(child_index);

});
```

```css
.div{
position:absolute;
left:45%;
top:0;
}
.child{
margin:1%;
text-align:center;
background-color:gray;
width:100px;
height:100px;
}

.c1,.c2{
color:white;
background-color:blue;
}
.c2{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="c1">c1</div>
    <div class="c2">c2</div>
    <p>click only work on <strong>c1</strong></p>
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <div class="c1">c1</div>
    <div class="c2">c2</div>
    <p>click only work on <strong>c1</strong></p>
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <div class="c1">c1</div>
    <div class="c2">c2</div>
    <p>click only work on <strong>c1</strong></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
var child_index = ''; //to store .child class parent index when clicked

$('.c1').click(function() {

    var parent = $(this).parent(); //getting the specific parent of c1

    //parent variable value now is = .child
    child_index = $(parent).index();

    alert(child_index);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it returns -1 every time is because in Jquery -1 is a boolean for false and 0 is true. .index() basically asks whether an element exists.

If you want to find what number it is this is a code which I think would work.

```
var loop = $('.parent .child').length;

$('.child .c1').click(function(){
    for(i=1; i<= loop; i++) {
         if($(this).parent() === $('.parent').children().eq(i)) {
             alert(i);
         }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT Since no one can reproduce the problem, here are some possibilities:**

- The version of jQuery you're using is conflicting with another script on your page. Since it seems your click event handler is firing because your getting an alert box.
- - Try using the latest version of jQuery.
- Your version of jQuery is conflicting with the current browser you are using. When you're having JavaScript issues you should report the versions of the library you are using (if any) and of your browser.
- - Check your results in another browser and report back.
- Your HTML is being manipulated before your click event is fired. What other code do you have on the page?
- - Share a more complete source code listing.

---

```
alert($(this).parent().prevAll().length);
```

Use .prevAll to get all previous siblings, then use the length of that set as your index.

**edit** Use .prevAll(".child") if you are expecting other elements that you want to ignore for indexing purposes.

**edit** You could try removing jQuery all together

```
var elms=document.getElementsByClassName("c1");
for(var i=0; i<elms.length; i++)
    elms[i].onclick = function() {
        var elm = this;
        var index = 0;
        elm = elm.parentNode;
        if(elm) {
            while(elm=elm.previousSibling) {
                if(elm.nodeType == 1) {
                    index++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            alert("There's no parent node");
        }
        alert(index);
    };
```

Comment: Isn't that essentially what `.index()` does? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Barmar - I don't think I'm re-inventing any wheel here. Just offering another correct (emphasis on correct) answer. Oh well too each his own.

Comment: The trouble is that if OP's code is returning `-1` as a result of calling `.index()` on `$(this).parent()`, then yours will also return `-1`, so it doesn't really help with the problem. ...or actually, it'll return `0`, even if `.parent()` didn't match anything, giving a false positive.

Comment: That's what my comment states. At first I said `-1` to indicate the undesired result, but then noted that it would actually be `0`, which would be worse, because it would make it look like something was found.

Comment: @CrazyTrain - Since no one but the OP is getting the claimed result, it must be that he's using different markup from what he's showing us OR he's using an exotic combination of jQuery version and browser. In any case, given the current markup and script provided by the OP my code snippet will run correctly. I can't read peoples minds, so until it's elaborated on further by the OP, I'll leave my correct answer.

Comment: If OP wants the 0-based index, then your solution is incorrect as there will be an incorrect `0` result when there's no matched element. In other words, OP's original code is better than your answer.

Comment: @CrazyTrain - with the current markup shared by the OP my code will always work correctly. Notice the selector of the .click event, in the current scenario there is always a parent and it is always a div with a class of 'child'. You're preference for a -1 result when no parent is found may or may not be the OP's preference. This has nothing to do with the OP's actual problem, so it's a waste to argue subjective semantics.

Comment: *"This has nothing to do with the OP's actual problem..."* Nor does your "solution".

Comment: @CrazyTrain - "This" was referring to the unproductive discussion with you in the comment, not the answer. :) I was supplying an alternative approach that didn't use .index, perhaps the OP has some code that breaks the index function, since no one can reproduce the problem you have to make some assumptions about what it could be right?

Comment: Yes, one can make assumptions, but I fail to see how some means of breaking `.index()` wouldn't also break your solution. jQuery basically implements `.index()` by using `.prevAll()` on the first element in the jQuery object. Only difference is that they first check that an element exists, and is in the DOM, and if not, returns `-1`. The `-1` wasn't my preference. It was OP's since `.index()` was being used.

Comment: @CrazyTrain - http://jsfiddle.net/94aRY/  There is an example of breaking .index without breaking .prevAll. Short answer $.fn.index=function(){return -1;} "The result is -1 all the time. What could be wrong?" I wouldn't be surprised if OP was a college psych professor researching how people go about trying to solve unsolvable problems, but that's just another assumption.

Comment: And so your solution to `$.fn.index=function(){return -1;}` would be to use `.prevAll().length`, and not to fix the overridden method? And of course if you're going to stretch that far, then `.prevAll()` could be overridden as well.

Comment: @CrazyTrain - There's your fallacy, .prevAll "could" be overridden as well, but the OP's question showed the use of .index not .prevAll. I should of also provided a non .parent() solution as well since we can only assume the event handling is working properly from the OP's question.

Comment: Wow, you really have a knack for missing the point. Point is that if `.index()` is overridden with something ridiculous, the appropriate solution is to revert that override rather than to use an alternate solution which itself may or may not be overridden. And again, since OP wants the 0-based `.index()`, your solution has the "benefit" of providing a false `0` result.

Comment: @CrazyTrain - May you could also assume OP was overriding .index on purpose so that it would return 0 on fault, but his patch job sadly failed. But I can't read minds so presuming what the OP 'wants' is just rhetoric. So again, "this has nothing to do with the OP's actual problem".

Comment: Except somehow through all these hypothetical situations you're creating, your solution is deemed relevant. This entire conversation proves my point. Without knowing more details, your "solution" isn't helpful. I'm the one looking at what ***was*** provided, and saying your solution won't help. *You're* the one inventing situations to try to make your answer seem relevant. Are you truly so insecure that you can't be at all corrected?

Comment: @CrazyTrain - Excellent 8 comments before you resorted to ad hominem. All you've offered so far is that, in your opinion, my answer is not relevant. The fact that I don't agree with you seems to be what's causing insecurity for yourself, but I'm perfectly happy with my current answer and have no issue with you having an opinion about it.

Comment: Not at all. I'm merely asking a question. But you seem to need positive reinforcement irrespective of reality, so here you go. Great answer! I'm sure it'll really help OP solve the issue! Super job!

Comment: @CrazyTrain - You're getting flustered over an answer to an unsolvable problem. Try to broaden your perspective a bit.

Comment: Oh no. Not flustered at all. Just pointing out that your answer is wrong, or at best, off-topic for the question.

Comment: @CrazyTrain - If you were "Just pointing out" something it would not have taken 10 comments, I'll try not to make assumptions about how you feel purely based on text though. There can be more than one right answer, some of the answers (even if you don't like them) may help lead to solution; this is especially true for unprovable questions like the OPs.

Comment: I was just pointing it out. But you kept leaving me comments, so I would offer the courtesy of a response in order to correct you. Irrespective of this, given the information in the question, your answer is wrong, or at best, off-topic.

Comment: @CrazyTrain - "Are you truly so insecure that you can't be at all corrected? "-CrazyTrain, doesn't appear to be courteous. Considering this is my answer, it would in fact be you who is leaving me comments, and me who is replying to them. So again, there can be more than one right answer, some of the answers (even if you don't like them) may help lead to a solution; this is especially true for unprovable questions like the OPs

Comment: The courtesy is in taking the time to reply. The initial communication was in the form of your answer, which opens you to comments and corrections. My initial comment was in reply to your answer. You should be thanking me for taking the time to correct you.

Comment: @CrazyTrain - Perhaps you should add your own answer rather than wasting your effort 'correcting' mine? Usually when you correct someone you offer a solution, since you clearly have no solution, you're only engaging in a petty game of semantics. If you wish to be thanked, do something constructive. Frankly, I've been mildly entertained by the lengths you'll go. So, thank you, for vehemently expressing your dissatisfaction with my answer to an unprovable question. There's no need to respond I've had more than enough of your courtesy.

Comment: I've not answered because there's not enough information. I don't believe my efforts with you are wasted, as I refuse to believe you're entirely beyond hope. I've not argued semantics, but only that your answer is a lesser version of what OP is already doing, and as such, can be of no help in the actual situation. Sadly, you've chosen to make this about you, and how you mustn't be corrected, rather than about actually trying to find a solution. Your updated answer is certainly better than the original, but is at best an instructional comment, as the question was not "how to debug".

Comment: @CrazyTrain - If you have nothing constructive to offer then there is no need to respond, unless you need to have the 'last word' but that's just petty. Your efforts are completely wasted; I'm utterly beyond hope; I'll continue taking cracks at questions with 'not enough information'.

Comment: Well, my comments certainly have been very relevant and constructive, as is this one, and I don't think you're unable to learn, but I'll grant that you're simply unwilling. Still, I don't think my efforts are wasted, as I don't believe it's ever a waste to try to help someone who needs it. If you wish to respond, I won't try to accuse you of being petty or not constructive, but I won't bother to respond at this point. Best of luck.

Comment: ...oops, just noticed you updated your answer. Your non-jQuery solution is flawed in that the `else` is part of the `if` statement in the `while` loop, irrespective of the indentation. If you're going to elide curly braces with your `if/else` statements, it can be a useful practice to include an `else` with an empty statement for nested `if`s, as in: `if(elm.nodeType == 1) index++; else ;`

Comment: @CrazyTrain - You've found my error and offered constructive criticism to correct it. All fixed, it appears our work here is done.